# React component unit test with enzyme fails when rendering Image tag with svg

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, enzyme

I am using React with Typescript and using Jest and Enzyme for unit testing. I am trying to unit test the following component (simplified, of course):

```
import image1 from 'path/to/image1.svg';
import image2 from 'path/to/image2.svg';

export const ShowImage: React.StatelessComponent<{isTab1: boolean, someId: number, isTab2: boolean }> = ({ isTab1, someId, isTab2}) => (
    <td>
        {isTab1 !== true && someId === 1 && !isTab2 ?
            <Image1 />
            :
            null
        }
        {isTab1 !== true && someId === 2 && !isTab2 ?
            <Image2 />
            :
            null
        }
    </td>
);

export const Image1 = () => (
    <Image src={image1} />
);

export const Image2 = () => (
    <Image src={image2} />
);
```

The `Image` tag is a React Bootstrap tag.  I am testing the `ShowImage` component in a test file like so:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import { mount, shallow } from 'enzyme';
import * as Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-15';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

function setupShowImageComponent(isTab1: boolean, someId: number, isTab2: boolean): any {
    const props = {
        isTab1: isTab1,
        someId: someId,
        isTab2: isTab2
    };

    const enzymeWrapper = mount(<ShowImage {...props} />);

    return {
        props,
        enzymeWrapper
    }
}

describe('Test ShowImage Component', () => {
    it('false, 1, false', () => {
        const { enzymeWrapper } = setupShowImageComponent(false, 1, false);

        expect(enzymeWrapper.find('td')).toHaveLength(1);    
        expect(enzymeWrapper.find('Image1')).toHaveLength(1); // fails: receives length 0
        expect(enzymeWrapper.find('Image2')).toHaveLength(0);
    });

    it('false, 2, false', () => {
        const { enzymeWrapper } = setupShowImageComponent(false, 2, false);

        expect(enzymeWrapper.find('td')).toHaveLength(1);    
        expect(enzymeWrapper.find('Image1')).toHaveLength(0);
        expect(enzymeWrapper.find('Image2')).toHaveLength(1); // fails: receives length 0
    });
});
```

Both of these tests fail. Other React components that I am testing pass fine but this one eludes me.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. It is important to note that this used to work but when I migrated my code over to use TypeScript, these two tests failed.

**UPDATE**

After some experimentation, if I test for the existence of the `Image` tag rather than `Image1` or `Image2` it works. It seems that it does not recognize the functional component but rather its children instead? I'm confused here. How can I test if it's specifically `Image1` or `Image2` instead of just testing `Image`? Again, this worked in with Javascript but is not working with TypeScript.

Comment: are all expect failing?

Comment: @eramit2010 oops sorry I forgot to indicate where the expectations are failing. I've updated my original post.

Comment: can you try with importing Image1 and Image2 and then find imported components instead of string. It's wierd solution but sometimes it works for me.

Comment: @eramit2010 hey, you and I discovered the same solution! If you want to write up a solution, I'd be happy to accept and give you credit for it.

Comment: I have faced same issue in past and importing component works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that works. Instead of doing:

```
expect(enzymeWrapper.find('Image1')).toHaveLength(1); // fails
```

do:

```
expect(enzymeWrapper.find(Image1)).toHaveLength(1); // passes
```

I'm not sure if this is the best solution but it's something that gets me past my issues.